# Does Windows Firewall block ICMP Timestamp Request (Type 13) by default?

Tags: networking, firewall, wireshark, windows-firewall, icmp

This question is specifically related to the ICMPv4 Timestamp Request (Type 13) message.

When I have Windows Firewall **disabled** I can send a Timestamp Request from the host and the client will receive the request and respond with Timestamp Reply (Type 14).

When I have Windows Firewall **enabled** I can send a Timestamp Request from the host and the client will receive the request but never responds with Timestamp Reply.  I'm assuming this is because the firewall is blocking the request.  However, I don't see any particular rules setup which indicate to me that this is really the case.  Neither could I find any documentation online to help me understand if this particular message is being blocked by default (like ICMP Echo).

Does anyone know if Windows Firewall blocks this message by default?  Is there somewhere I can look to see/configure this default setting?  Is there documentation available somewhere that I simply missed?

I am using Nping to send the message and Wireshark to watch the packets come and go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Firewall blocks *everything* by default. The full processing order is documented [on TechNet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/13894.troubleshooting-windows-firewall-with-advanced-security-in-windows-server-2012.aspx#Rules_are_evaluated_in_a_specific_order), but for simplicity, you can think of it as "1) handle all 'deny' rules, 2) handle all 'allow' rules, 3) deny or allow everything else, depending on profile settings".

When you open the firewall configuration tool (either by running **`wf.msc`**, or opening the *"Windows Firewall with Advanced Security"* app, or clicking the "[image: Advanced Settings]" link in Control Panel), you see this screen:

[image: (Screenshot of wf.msc indicating the profiles' global policy)]

By default, this says "Inbound connections that do not match a rule are blocked", and this really applies to *all* packets not associated with an existing state, including ICMP requests. If you haven't found any specific rules related to Timestamp Requests, that means they will be denied as per the default configuration.

So in order to allow specific ICMP types, you should of course create rules under "Inbound Rules", or enable those which already exist. For example, the "File and Printer Sharing" group has built-in rules to allow incoming ICMP 'Echo Request':

[image: (Screenshot of wf.msc rules allowing ICMP Echo)]

The specific ICMP types for each rule are selected under "Protocols and Ports → ICMP settings: Customize". (In order to allow Timestamp Request, you must create a custom rule; the list is read-only for built-in rules).

[image: (Screenshot of wf.msc rule creation wizard)]
[image: (Screenshot of wf.msc rule parameters, listing ICMP types and subtypes)]

Finally, however, note that even if the firewall *allows* the packets through, that doesn't mean the OS will actually *support* that specific ICMP request type. As ICMPv4 "Timestamp Request" is fairly rare (rare enough to not have a built-in rule in Windows Firewall, and outright has no equivalent in ICMPv6), there is no real guarantee that future Windows versions won't "deprecate" and remove code for responding to such requests...

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  I needed to take a step back and realize that the firewall is blocking everything except for what any rules might allow for.  Seems I was too mired in looking for Timestamp Request "stuff" specifically.  I looked right past that part of the overview screen every time I opened it... Also, great last comment.  I agree completely.

Answer (score -1):

`UDP` is inherently "dumb", as in; simple -- not sophisticated. There is more-often-than-not, no requirement that the requests return anything, or succeed at all. It's pretty dry reading, but you'd probably find [RFC-792](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc792) a good read in your situation. As to a cure; if it were me, I'd probably open up `echo req`, and see if you don't get a better return value on your requests.

While not a Windows man(ual) page. The following FreeBSD man page should help in better understanding all the details of [ICMP](https://manpage.me/?icmp)

Comment: Since they are two separate protocols, I assume you meant to say "ICMP" instead of "UDP"?  My question is more pointed in that I (seemingly) see Windows Firewall blocking ICMP message Timestamp Request, but I don't know why.  I don't see anything that would indicate that this message should be blocked.

Comment: `ICMP` is a "building block" of the larger, more complex `IP` protocol/packet. Much like `UDP` it is **un**sophisticated. Which is why I chose it. :) While not a Windows man page. I've added a FreeBSD man page which should provide you with a better understanding as to *why* you're having trouble receiving a reply, and what *not* to block in Windows (I already made a suggestion in the original reply). :)

Comment: Both `ICMP`, and `UDP` are **datagrams**. Is `Timestamp Reply` (**14**) blocked?