# LAN computer error when i try to ping: timeout

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, ping

**Hello everyone.**

I am trying to ping a local connected computer (PC 2).

Both PCs are WIN 10 and are connected to the router; PC 1 is connected via Wireless and PC 2 is connected via Ethernet.

When I try to `ping` (PC 1 > PC 2), it throws **TIMED OUT** ('Tiempo de espera agotado.'), same with `tracert`.

When I check the router in the browser, both devices are connected successfully. I tried several things and I can contact the device in many ways, for example: contact it via local servers in both directions, detection with applications like `arp-scan`, list it in `arp -a` and many more, but NOT ping.

I think this is really weird and I don't know how to fix it, and an application needs it to check that the device is reachable and its host is UP.

Comment: For clarity: are PC1 and PC2 on the same router? If the wireless router is separate, is wireless isolation enabled?

Comment: look for a setting in your router wireless config called "ap isolation", or "client isolation" or "wifi isolation" and disable it if on. its designed to let people use the wifi without being able to hack eachother. useful in coffee shops and waiting rooms, but not very helpful for a personal LAN that uses wireless.

Comment: @FrankThomas I tried doing it, same with connecting both devices to ethernet and still not working. :(

Comment: are both windows systems networks set as Private? try `test-netconnection` in powershell instead of ping. if there is a known network service on the unresponsive PC, you can test it with `test-netconnection <IP_ADDR> -p <portnumber>`. 445 is usually open on windows systems that are configured to allow file sharing between them.

Comment: @FrankThomas nothing, It continue saying "timed out " when finish for waiting for the echo.
Another example: I can not do a socket.gethostbyaddr(remotehost) (throws "host not found"), but I perfectly can connect to that device with socket.connect(remotehost)

Comment: are both systems networks set to "private" so that it uses the Private firewall profile?

Comment: @FrankThomas Yep :( both networks are setted as private, I checked it several times with methods like powershell command:  'Get-NetConnectionProfile'

Answer (score 0):

It's probably that ingoing ICMP packets are [blocked](https://superuser.com/questions/1454135/does-windows-firewall-block-icmp-timestamp-request-type-13-by-default) [by](https://superuser.com/questions/1708119/allowing-icmp-ping-incoming-packets-in-windows-11-firewall) the Windows firewall or ICMP is blocked by the router.

To create a firewall rule that allows it, run this in "Command Prompt" cmd.exe

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Ping" protocol=ICMPV4 dir=in action=allow
```

or this in Powershell

```
New-NetFirewallRule -Name "Ping" -Protocol ICMPv4 -Direction Inbound -Action Allow
```

<sub>[Source](https://superuser.com/questions/1137912/ping-to-windows-10-not-working-if-file-and-printer-sharing-is-turned-off/1627195#1627195)</sub>

There are many variants of these instructions online, like [this on Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/operating-system-security/network-security/windows-firewall/create-an-inbound-icmp-rule). Search for [Windows Firewall allow ping](https://www.google.com/search?q=Windows%20Firewall%20allow%20ping) or alike to get an impression.